# Возможно ли отменить CCS свойство дочернему элементу?

Tags: html, css3, filter, blur

```css
.all {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    align-content: center;
    justify-items: stretch;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    grid-gap: 2em;
    filter: blur(5px);
}
.all nav {
    filter: blur(0px) !important;
}

.cbp-spmenu {
 background: #fff;
 position: fixed;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.cbp-spmenu h3 {
 font-weight: 300;
    background: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Marmelad', sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #25a2c3;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0 0.75em 0.5em 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #333;
}
.major {
    padding: 0 1em;
   display: flex;
}
.major a {
    margin: 3em 0;
}
.major a {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    color: #25a2c3 !important;
    border: 1px solid #25a2c3;
    padding: 11px 24px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1.7em 1em 0em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #25a2c3 !important;
}
.major a:hover {
    background: #25a2c3 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 17px rgba(37, 162, 195, 0.7) !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    transition: 0.3s !important;
}

.cbp-spmenu a {
 display: block;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:hover {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}

.cbp-spmenu a:active {
 background: #afdefa;
 color: #47a3da;
}

/* Orientation-dependent styles for the content of the menu */

.cbp-spmenu-vertical {
 width: 18em;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.cbp-spmenu-vertical a {
 padding: 0.7em 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal h3 {
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal a {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 padding: 0.8em;
 border-left: 1px solid #258ecd;
}

/* Vertical menu that slides from the left or right */

.cbp-spmenu-left {
 left: -22em;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right {
 right: -240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-left.cbp-spmenu-open {
 left: 0px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right.cbp-spmenu-open {
 right: 0px;
}

/* Horizontal menu that slides from the top or bottom */

.cbp-spmenu-top {
 top: -150px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-bottom {
 bottom: -150px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-top.cbp-spmenu-open {
 top: 0px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-bottom.cbp-spmenu-open {
 bottom: 0px;
}

/* Push classes applied to the body */

.cbp-spmenu-push {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
}

.cbp-spmenu-push-toright {
 left: 240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-push-toleft {
 left: -240px;
}

/* Transitions */

.cbp-spmenu,
.cbp-spmenu-push {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<body class="all">
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left cbp-spmenu-open" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">
        <ul>
          <li>Один</li>
          <li>Два</li>
          <li>Три</li>
          <li>Четыре</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>A blanditiis, ab. Commodi at provident necess itatibus animi consequuntur veritatis nesciunt, totam, natus quo saepe cupiditate molitia eveniet iste deleniti A blanditiis, ab. Commodi at provident necess itatibus animi consequuntur veritatis nesciunt, totam, natus quo saepe cupiditate molitia eveniet iste deleniti A blanditiis, ab. Commodi at provident necess itatibus animi consequuntur veritatis nesciunt, totam, natus quo saepe cupiditate molitia eveniet iste deleniti A blanditiis, ab. Commodi at provident necess itatibus animi consequuntur veritatis nesciunt, totam, natus quo saepe cupiditate molitia eveniet iste deleniti</main>
    <footer>Подвал</footer>
</body>
```

При открытии меню к `nav` добавляется класс .open. При закрытии удаляется.
Возможно ли применить `filter: blur(2px)` к `body`, при этом исключив `nav`? Возможно псевдокласс `:not` может помочь?

Comment: То, что Вы хотите сделать, увы, не получится, т.к. дочерние элементы наследуют css-правила родителя - [похожий вопрос на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080365/css-to-prevent-child-element-from-inheriting-parent-styles). Но, Вы можете использовать `!important` для дочерних элементов, чтобы "переписать" родительское значение.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что значение не переписывается.

Comment: Приложите код в вопрос.

Comment: Приложил. В стилях как вы и писали, применил !important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```js
var btnMenu = document.querySelector('.btn-menu');
var body = document.querySelector('body');


function myFunc() {

  this.classList.toggle('open');
  body.classList.toggle('layer-blur');

}
btnMenu.addEventListener('click', myFunc);
```

```css
.btn-menu {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

.open {
  background: #00f;
  color: #fff;
}

body.layer-blur:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://assets.rbl.ms/6461854/980x.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<body class="all">

  <button class="btn-menu">Menu</button>

</body>
```

Comment: не совсем то, что я имел виду. Фильтр нужно применить к уже существующей разметке, а не к новому фону.

Comment: @Санжар - так как вы хотите не получиться

Comment: @Санжар - вам и менять не особо много, всего лишь использовать псевдоэлемент для body